# Optimal Only - Least stops and which ones

Tags: algorithm

What is the most OPTIMAL algorithm, to give an 'Array of Station numbers' FOR LEAST TIMES OF REFUELLING for a route from P1 to Pn, where Pi is a Petrol filling station,

1 <= i <= n,
(including the starting point P1 and destination Pn).

● The Distance vector Dist [1.....,n-1], where, n = total number of available petrol stations and Dist [i] is the distance from Pi to Pi+1.

● The vector will be the set, Dist [P1 – P2,......, Pn-1 – Pn] respectively.

ASSUMPTIONS :-

1.Each Petrol station has filled up your car’s petrol tank full tank.

2.Your car can travel ‘d’ miles, once it has been filled with a full tank of ‘p’ litres.

3 The distance between petrol stations is assumed not to be greater than ‘d’ (Dist [i] <= d). (That is the car cant run out of fuel midway in between stations if it just refuelled)

4.You start your journey with a full tank of petrol from P1.

Comment: If the car is on P1, what options does it have other than going to P2?

Comment: Its a Linear path going from P1 to P2 to P3 ... to PN. It's only choice is if it wants to stop in any stop between for refuelling, and it has to maintain LEAST number of stops of refuelling. It can go to P2, but doesn't mean it will stop there for a refuel.

Comment: Simply traverse the Dist array and maintain the current distance traveled (accumulative sum starting from 0 and adding Dist[i]) and whenever this sum exceeds d, then you have to stop at station i-1.

Comment: Hint: 1 pass, `O(n)` solution.

Answer (score 0):

The greedy approach is optimal. Always go to the most distant station you can reach without refueling. O(n).

Why? Say A, B, and C are three stations along the route in the order reached, and from station A you could visit B or C without refueling. If you refuel at B, then when you reach C you have as many stops as you would if you had stopped at C instead, but less fuel.